# Issue getting data popup to close with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following method to make pop-ups open and close before, but in this case I cannot get the pop up to close. Does anyone see anything standing out within my close code which would not allow the pop up to close?

```
<div id="new-profile-pic-preview">
    <form>
        <img class="none pic-preview" id="file" src="#" alt="your image">
        <input type="submit" class="none" name="create" value="Upload Profile Picture">
    </form>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#upload-link").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#upload-profile-pic:hidden").trigger('click');
});
//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So what is `data-popup` ? there is no element with this attribute in your code here

Comment: @EhsanT Whenever I do data-popup-close, it simply makes the word "Close" go away and not the pop-up. The popup is `new-profile-pic-preview`. Any ideas?

Comment: So just to be clear, what you want is: when you click on this link `<a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>`, this div `<div id="new-profile-pic-preview">` becomes invisible. did I get it right?

Comment: @EhsanT Yes. That is correct.

Comment: OK then, why don't you simply use `$('#new-profile-pic-preview').fadeOut(350);` instead of `$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);`?

Comment: @EhsanT That worked. Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your code and our brief chat in the comments, all you need to do is to choose the correct element to `fadeOut`

So the code which is responsible for closing the pupop would be like this:

```
//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('[#new-profile-pic-preview').fadeOut(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```